# Problemas para imprimir emojis en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

soy bastante novato en la programación. Estoy haciendo un bootcamp en el que uno de los retos es un hundir la flota. Para el tablero, he creado un array de numpy con  de forma que se asemeje al mar. Este se imprime bien en Visual Studio Code, pero cuando lo intento correr con el Python Shell de Windows (botón derecho y abrir con Python, en vez de abrir con Visual Studio Code), lo que se imprime son muchos símbolos de interrogación. Estamos, el grupo, pensando en dejar solo espacios, pero la verdad es que me gustaría que saliera así. ¿Alguien sabe la solución? He probado a hacerlo con el código de Unicode, con "import emoji" y con muchas cosas que he visto en Google y en ChatGPT... nada parece funcionar. Aquí parte del código. Muchas gracias.

```
def tablero(Tm):

nosotros = np.full((Tm, Tm), "")
ordenador = np.full((Tm, Tm), "")
separador = np.full((Tm+1, 2), "")  
numeros_de_columnas = []  # Para las fila con los números que indican las columnas necesitamos crear una lista vacia
for i in range(1, Tm + 1):  #vamos recorriendo el rango (empezando en 1, no en 0, y terminando en Tm(o sea, uno más))
    if i < 10:  
        numeros_de_columnas.append(" "+str(i))  #A los número de un digito le añado un espacio para que queden bien y no se amontonen.
    else:
        numeros_de_columnas.append(str(i))   
nosotros_columna= np.vstack((nosotros, numeros_de_columnas))
ordenador_columna= np.vstack((ordenador, numeros_de_columnas))
pantallas= np.hstack((nosotros_columna, separador,ordenador_columna))
espacio_vacio= np.array([[" "]]) #para que pueda unir matrices con distinta dimension necesito añadir espacios vacios
columnasletras = np.array([chr((i % 26) + 65) if i < 26 else chr((i % 26) + 97) for i in range(Tm)]).reshape(-1, 1)#esta linea es bastante complicada, lo hice con gpt.
columna_de_letras =np.vstack((columnasletras, espacio_vacio))
columna_de_filas_vacias = np.array([[" "]]*(Tm+1)) #para que la columna de letras que indican los nombres de las filas no se amontonen (en la pantalla derecha) usamos una columna vacia.
pantallas_con_filas = np.hstack((columna_de_letras, pantallas,columna_de_filas_vacias, columna_de_letras))
return pantallas_con_filas
```

Comment: Ley de programación sin importar el lenguaje: Haz lo más básico posible y de ahí vas subiendo el nivel. Antes de aventurarte a hacer emojis, primero revisa si te funciona con letras o números, algo simple. Por otro lado, acostúmbrate a leer, la identación (sangragías o espaciados) en python es vital. Lecturas obligatorias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Comment: Si, si en vez de los cuadraditos uso letras, funciona perfectamente. Leere las lecturas obligatorias, gracias.

Comment: Esto, más que un problema de Python, es una limitación de la terminal en lo referente al soporte de unicode o la fuente usada por la misma. Los símbolos de interrogación son el [carácter de reemplazo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character). En principio o configuras la terminal para que funcione correctamente con estos caracteres (si es posible) o usas otra compatible para ejecutar el programa. Otra opción  es usar una interfaz gráfica en vez de CLI.